# Seeking ArcPy equivalents for SPLINE and SETWINDOW commands from ArcInfo Workstation?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, arcinfo-workstation, aml

I know of a [list of conversions between AML and ArcPy](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/geoprocessing/pdf/Python_equivalents_to_AML_functions_and_directives.pdf).

I was wondering if anyone knew of another resource to go between the two? In particular I am looking for a SETWINDOW (AML) function  in ArcPy, and I am trying to understand what the SPLINE function does in AML, and trying to figure out if its the same as the Spline tool in ArcGIS.

Comment: There are a couple of questions here.  Look [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001w00000009000000) for arcpy equivalent of SETWINDOW.

Comment: Please ask only one question per question as per the [Tour].

Answer (score 1):

I do not have access to the SPLINE command documentation of ArcInfo Workstation, but my recollection is that it was a command for "smoothing" the coordinates of **vector** features, whereas [Spline](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z0000006q000000) from ArcGIS for Desktop:

> Interpolates a **raster** surface from points using a two-dimensional
>   minimum curvature spline technique.

I did not use the GRID module of ArcInfo Workstation frequently enough to recall whether it had another command called SPLINE for raster data.

---

As commented by @Barbarossa:

> Look
>   `[`[at the Output Extent (Environment setting) documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001w00000009000000)`]`
>   for arcpy equivalent of SETWINDOW.

Answer (score 0):

Arc/Info Spline - smooths or generalizes all currently selected arcs using the GRAIN tolerance.
The Arcpy equivelant is probably Cartography Smooth Line.

Setwindow - sets the window of the current analysis environment in the GRID module.
 The Arcpy equivalent is probably env.extent
[image]
[image]